# How to call a string in another class in java

Tags: java, string, class

I'm a real noob so please if i ain't asking corectly sorry.

So here it is :

```
 public class carti extends JFrame {
    JTextField txttitlu;
    JTextField txtautor;
    JTextField txtcat;
    JTextField txtedi;
    JTextField txtpret;
    DefaultListModel model;
    JList lista;
    String editura;
    String titlu;
    String autor;
    String categorie;
```

This is the main class function that i have,and in this class i have 4 JTextFields that ar inserted into a JList by a button(here is the script for the adding button"caled "adauga"):

```
 public void Adauga() {

        autor = txtautor.getText().trim();
        titlu = txttitlu.getText().trim();
        categorie = txtcat.getText().trim();
        editura = txtedi.getText().trim();

        if (autor.equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nu ati completat Titlu!");
            return;
        }
        if (titlu.equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nu ati completat Autor!");
            return;
        }
        if (categorie.equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nu ati completat Categorie!");
            return;
        }
        String numeComplet = autor + " / " + titlu + " : " + categorie;
        model.addElement(numeComplet);

    }
```

So what i want is: what the button "Adauga" is adding to my JList to be shown onto my extended new class that is called "detalii"(and here it is the code from the new class that si created ("detalii") :

```
public detalii(){

    this.setTitle("Detalii despre Carte");
    setSize(400, 300);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocation(370, 150);
    setLayout(null);
    JLabel lbltitlu= new JLabel("Titlu" +" : "); 
    lbltitlu.setBounds(15, 5, 120, 25);
    this.add(lbltitlu);
    JLabel lblautor= new JLabel("Autor" +" : "); 
    lblautor.setBounds(15, 25, 120, 25);
    this.add(lblautor);
    JLabel lblcategorie= new JLabel("Categorie" +" : "); 
    lblcategorie.setBounds(15, 45, 120, 25);
    this.add(lblcategorie);
    JLabel lbleditura= new JLabel("Editura" +" : "  ); 
    lbleditura.setBounds(15, 65, 120, 25);
    this.add(lbleditura);

}
```

Thank you for the help and sorry if my explains are not done properly i'm really noob. Hope you can understand and did not waste your time.

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: The question is how do i add to the JLabels from "detalii" the values i got in the main class that is call "carti",and wich there are aded by the button Adauga to a JList that i have in the same class(hope you understand)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want the "detalii" class to have its labels updated with the information provided by the "Adauga" method. I would suppose one way of doing that is to call a method within "detalii" from the "Adauga" method.

This is how I would change "Adauga":

```
public void Adauga() {

    autor = txtautor.getText().trim();
    titlu = txttitlu.getText().trim();
    categorie = txtcat.getText().trim();
    editura = txtedi.getText().trim();

    if (autor.equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nu ati completat Titlu!");
        return;
    }
    if (titlu.equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nu ati completat Autor!");
        return;
    }
    if (categorie.equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nu ati completat Categorie!");
        return;
    }
    String numeComplet = autor + " / " + titlu + " : " + categorie;
    model.addElement(numeComplet);

    detalii.pushNewInfo(autor, titlu, categorie, editura);  // Add This Line!

}
```

And I would change "detalii" to the following:

```
private JLabel lbltitlu;
private JLabel lblautor;
private JLabel lbleditura;
private JLabel lblcategorie;

public detalii(){

    this.setTitle("Detalii despre Carte");
    setSize(400, 300);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocation(370, 150);
    setLayout(null);
    lbltitlu= new JLabel("Titlu" +" : "); 
    lbltitlu.setBounds(15, 5, 120, 25);
    this.add(lbltitlu);
    lblautor= new JLabel("Autor" +" : "); 
    lblautor.setBounds(15, 25, 120, 25);
    this.add(lblautor);
    lblcategorie= new JLabel("Categorie" +" : "); 
    lblcategorie.setBounds(15, 45, 120, 25);
    this.add(lblcategorie);
    lbleditura= new JLabel("Editura" +" : "  ); 
    lbleditura.setBounds(15, 65, 120, 25);
    this.add(lbleditura);
}

public void pushNewInfo(String author, String title, 
                        String category, String editor) {
    lblautor.setText("Autor : " + author);
    lbltitlu.setText("Titlu : " + title);
    lblcategorie.setText("Categorie : " + category);
    lbleditura.setText("Editura : " + editor);
}
```

This is probably not the best solution, but this is how I would solve your problem given the information you have provided.

Comment: Thank you for the info but it says : Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method pushNewInfo(String, String, String, String) from the type detalii . And if i have not posted enough details i will post more. Sorry i'm trying to do my best to explain and  very much i appreciate your help.

Comment: Ah yea, sorry about that. You will need to add the "static" keyword to the "pushNewInfo" method like so:

    public static void pushNewInfo(String author...

Hope that helps!